# How to render a part of page as Pdf

Tags: visualforce

I have a page that will be rendered as a PDF and the bottom of page will contain Button as Send which will send a PDF to account's email.Is it possible to render a part of a Visualforce page as PDF.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of duplication of the page, as suggested by one of the answers, I would suggest to add some parameter to url called **render** (for example).

Then, in page definition, you can use next construction:

```
<apex:page 
renderAs="{!IF(ISNULL($CurrentPage.parameters.render),'',$CurrentPagePage.parameters.render)} 
... />
```

Then about sections. Lets say you have some outputPanel or another block that you don't want to display on PDF. You can easily do:

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="none" rendered="{!IF($CurrentPage.parameters.render = 'pdf',false, true)} />
```

Using that approach, you can hide/show sections based render type on demand.

Then, as a result, if you open your page as **`/apex/Mypage?<some params>&render=pdf`** - it would be rendered as pdf, and if **`/apex/MyPage?<some params>`** - it would be rendered as html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's only possible to display the whole page as a PDF using the "renderas=PDF" attribute of the apex:page tag. So you can't display only part of the page, since apex:page is always the root.

What you could do is display a VF page where the user has two options (two buttons or links): Preview Send (they see the PDF) or Actually Send (the email/PDF is sent).

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the same page and only leave the part that you want as PDF. Then from the first page via the button redirect to your other page which will contain `renderAs="PDF"`

Comment: As an alternative to duplicating the page, there is [PageReference.getContentAsPdf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_getContentAsPDF.htm) that "Returns the page in PDF, regardless of the <apex:page> component’s
> renderAs attribute".

Comment: That will return the whole page though, he needs only a section

Comment: ... meant to say "and include conditional rendering".

Comment: @KeithC The conditional rendering would need to make the sendPDF button conditional since you can't render active content in a PDF document.

Answer (score 0):

```
the bottom of page will contain Button as Send which will send a PDF to account's email
```

A PDF cannot be rendered with active content. As others have said, you'll need to rerender the portion of the page you want to send in a new window and attach it to an email.